# How to get all restrictions on an individual in Jena

Tags: java, jena, ontology, owl

my ontology has a Road class, and a shop class.

The Road class has an individual called 'highstreetroad' which is related to 8 different shop individuals.

I'm trying to print all the existing statements where 'Road hasShop Shop'. There should be 8 statements, but it only ever gives me one. I am using Jena to do this. Here is an example from my code:

```
ExtendedIterator<Individual> i = model.listIndividuals(RoadCls);
        while (i.hasNext())
        {
          Individual indi = i.next();
          System.out.println( indi.getProperty(hasShopCls) );
        }
```

I believe the reason is due to the 'getProperty' as the javadoc says that only one will be returned, but i want more than one:

> "Answer some statement (this, p, O) in the associated model. If there are several such statements, any one of them may be returned. If no such statements exist, null is returned - in this is differs from getRequiredProperty."

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case, you want [`OntResource.listPropertyValues`](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntResource.html#listPropertyValues%28com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Property%29).

Comment: Thanks Ian, I've just tried your suggestion, and the i get the following result on running:com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.NodeIteratorImpl@99e1fe
com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.NodeIteratorImpl@c41a30
com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.NodeIteratorImpl@e5b079
com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.NodeIteratorImpl@182ce41
com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.NodeIteratorImpl@130ca95
com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.NodeIteratorImpl@17b0c1b
com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.NodeIteratorImpl@a50144
com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.NodeIteratorImpl@af257d  could you suggest why this may be the case? thanks

Comment: I got it, this is what i did for anyone with the same problem - listPropertyValues(properties).toList();

Comment: I don't see a problem: what you get back from `listPropertyValues` is an iterator, a standard Java pattern. Jena extends standard iterators to also provide a `toList` method, as you found, but typically you would consume the iterator in a `for` or `while` loop. Materialising the iterator into a list is fine for small lists, but may be memory intensive if there are many values.

Comment: thanks Ian, I just used it as an iterator as you have advised and it works fine